# Labelling color bar in a heat map

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to add labels to the color bar. I only have discrete states to be marked.

For eg: In the figure shown below, (color bar value at 3 should be labelled as Gd condition, color bar value at 2 should be labelled as Bd condition, color bar value at 1 should be labelled as poor condition, color bar value at 0 should be labelled as very poor condition). I wrote a sample code to perform this operation. It doesnot seem to work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
figure
imagesc(transpose(all_area_for_visual));
colormap("jet")

colorbar('Ticks',[3,2,1,0],'TickLabels',{'Gd condition', 'Bd condition','Poor condition','Very poor condition'})
xlim([0,220000]);
xlabel('Time (s)')
ylabel('Car identity')
yticks(1:length(Ucolumnnames_fpm))
yticklabels([Ucolumnnames_fpm(1,:)])
```

[image]

Comment: Try `colorbar('Ticks',0:3,'TickLabels',{'Very poor condition', 'Poor condition', 'Bd condition', 'Gd condition'})` The values for `Ticks` property have to be arranged in ascending order.

Comment: Considering you only use 4 colors, try using `colormap(jet(4))`. I usually get very angry when people use `jet`, but since you only use 4 colors, it doesn't matter... :)